# Suddenly newly added anonymous pages prompting for login

Tags: anonymous-authentication

We are getting a strange issue. Until yesterday, we where able to add pages to site which have anonymous access enable. They were working as expected (no login prompt while accessing page). However today when we create a new anonymous page and try to access it, the page prompts for login.

Further more if we make changes to previously created pages and publish them. They work as expected (no login prompt).

What could be the issue.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Office 365 or on Premise?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thnx for your response. We have SharePoint 2010 Server (On Premise).

Comment: Did you check that the entire website has the anonymous access on? http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-9-turn-on-anonymous.html

Comment: yes website has anonymous access on. The site is live and users are able to acess it anonymously

Comment: OK, and did you check that the permission inheritance level is not broken on the Publishing Page List? You could follow the instruction on the following post to check your Anonymous configuration: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87534/list-set-for-anonymous-but-public-cannot-view

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for the link. I have narrowed the issue. It is happening for specific Layout pages (recently added). I checked for all the images, css and js files whether they are accessible anonymously. They all can be access anonymously.
Any guesses what could be wrong....

Comment: If you change the page with an old layout will the page get accessible for anonymous? Maybe the layout is not published? If you go to _catalogs/masterpage, double check the Page Layout is Published.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for continous support. The layout page is checked-in. Did some more trials and found that 1 of the Custom Controls has issue. When i remove custom control from layout page. It works. Add it back prompts for login again. But the strange thing is that is pretty old Custom control :(    (no changes done to in recent times)

Comment: This is a good thing, you are getting closer to solve the problem. Can you maybe paste here the code of the custom control?