# How to anonymously retrieving sharepoint list using ECMA script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using Sharepoint 2013. I am trying to retrieve a sharepoint list that contains list of all products from the server as an anonymous user using ECMA script/ JavaScript. I understand that it can be done using admin privileges and elevated rights. However, I want the user to be anonymous.

Can anyone give some suggestion how it can be done ??

edit 1: I am trying to achieve this feat purely using scripting code(ECMA/ JS). Is their possibly any way to do it ?

Comment: Please find an answer & let me know if it won't work....https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87534/list-set-for-anonymous-but-public-cannot-view

Comment: Actually, I am trying to avoid this method i.e. via site setting, as per the requirement, I am trying to do it through ECMA code. I am trying to access the list purely through code( ECMA / JS ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set list AnonymousPermMask using PowerShell below, then use JSOM to get list items.

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$siteurl = "[your site URL]"
$listname = "[your list name]"
$a = (get-spweb $siteurl).lists | where title -eq $listname
$a.AnonymousPermMask​64 = "ViewListItems, UseClientIntegration, UseRemoteAPIs"
```

As a workaround, we can create a custom web service to get list items from list that allows for anonymous access.

We can also create SharePoint Add-ins that can be used by anonymous users.

Refer to: [Create SharePoint Add-ins that can be used by anonymous users](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/sp-add-ins/create-sharepoint-add-ins-that-can-be-used-by-anonymous-users.md)